# rebuild part of page via listening to pageController

Tags: flutter, dart

what I have is column with a `PageView` and a Text below it.
what I want is to rebuild the text based on the `PageController`.

as I know the `PageController` extends ChangeNotifier and I am in search of sth like `ValueNotifier` which we can listen to it via `ValueListenableBuilder`.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `_myPageController.addListener((){ .... run checks like getting the actual page number});` ?

Comment: DaDash :) ! can you please more explain ... what do you want to do ? when the text should change ?

Comment: the text should change when page parameter of PageController changed

Answer (score 0):

I have create a custom widget based on `ValueListenableBuilder` which can accept a `ChangeNotifier` and call its builder callBack function:

**DISADVANTAGE:**
**I WANT ONLY CALL CALLBACK FUNCTION WHEN THE PAGE CHANGED BECAUSE IN THIS WAY, THE CALLBACK FUNCTION WILL BE CALLED MANY TIMES**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef ChangeWidgetBuilder = Widget Function(
  ChangeNotifier notifier,
  Widget child,
);

class ChangeListenableBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangeListenableBuilder({
    Key key,
    @required this.changeListenable,
    @required this.builder,
    this.child,
  })  : assert(changeListenable != null),
        assert(builder != null),
        super(key: key);

  final ChangeNotifier changeListenable;

  final ChangeWidgetBuilder builder;

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ChangeListenableBuilderState();
}

class _ChangeListenableBuilderState extends State<ChangeListenableBuilder> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.changeListenable.addListener(_valueChanged);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ChangeListenableBuilder oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.changeListenable != widget.changeListenable) {
      oldWidget.changeListenable.removeListener(_valueChanged);
      widget.changeListenable.addListener(_valueChanged);
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.changeListenable.removeListener(_valueChanged);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _valueChanged() => setState(() {});

  @override
  Widget build(_) => widget.builder(widget.changeListenable, widget.child);
}
```